# How can I get letsencrypt working with docker-compose for existing website that already has fullchain.pem

Tags: docker, ssl, nginx, docker-compose, lets-encrypt

I am working on getting Nginx to work with letsencrypt and docker-compose. That is, I am Dockerizing an existing website and running `docker-compose up` locally to verify everything is working. I am following [this really excellent article](https://medium.com/@pentacent/nginx-and-lets-encrypt-with-docker-in-less-than-5-minutes-b4b8a60d3a71) on Nginx and letsencrypt with Docker Compose. However, when I run `./init-letsencrypt.sh` I get the error:

```
### Reloading nginx ...
2020/07/05 10:27:43 [emerg] 32#32: cannot load certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/fullchain.pem": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/fullchain.pem','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)
nginx: [emerg] cannot load certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/fullchain.pem": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/fullchain.pem','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)
```

The site I am trying to get this working on is already running in production. **I have and can access `fullchain.pem` on my remote server.** To get letsencrypt to work locally using docker-compose for and existing website should I:

1. Copy this `fullchain.pem` file to my local machine and add `fullchain.pem` to my .gitignore?
2. Or is there another better way that is recommended for getting Nginx to work with letsencrypt on a local `docker-compose up` run?
3. Do I need to get a new certificate for this website to get letsencrypt working with docker-compose both locally and remote?
4. None of the above?

The full (modified) error message is below:

```
(base) ➜ ✗ ./init-letsencrypt.sh
Existing data found for <mysite>.com. Continue and replace existing certificate? (y/N) y
### Downloading recommended TLS parameters ...

### Creating dummy certificate for <mysite>.com ...
Generating a RSA private key
.............................+++++
...................+++++
writing new private key to '/etc/letsencrypt/live/<mysite>.com/privkey.pem'
-----

### Starting nginx ...
Recreating my_postgres ... done
Recreating <mysite>dotcom_django_web ... done
Recreating <mysite>dotcom_nginx_1    ... done

### Deleting dummy certificate for <mysite>.com ...

### Requesting Let's Encrypt certificate for <mysite>.com ...
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator webroot, Installer None

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Would you be willing to share your email address with the Electronic Frontier
Foundation, a founding partner of the Let's Encrypt project and the non-profit
organization that develops Certbot? We'd like to send you email about our work
encrypting the web, EFF news, campaigns, and ways to support digital freedom.
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
(Y)es/(N)o: No
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for <mysite>.com
http-01 challenge for www.<mysite>.com
Using the webroot path /var/www/certbot for all unmatched domains.
Waiting for verification...
Challenge failed for domain <mysite>.com
Challenge failed for domain www.<mysite>.com
http-01 challenge for <mysite>.com
http-01 challenge for www.<mysite>.com
Cleaning up challenges
Some challenges have failed.

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: <mysite>.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   https://<mysite>.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/Yw9a6TdSiXWltjD4T6fKWDiaCSJ4GDHCaBTdmKGdWmY
   [111.my.real.ip.111]: "<h1>Not Found</h1><p>The requested URL
   /.well-known/acme-challenge/Yw9a6TdSiXWltjD4T6fKWDiaCSJ4GDHCaBTdmKGdWmY
   was not found on "

   Domain: www.<mysite>.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   https://www.<mysite>.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/Ylt1PYbjJ4bRLHsW9Dtrx2wpq06M_zCOlCV9YGq4UNY
   [111.my.real.ip.111]: 400

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
 - Your account credentials have been saved in your Certbot
   configuration directory at /etc/letsencrypt. You should make a
   secure backup of this folder now. This configuration directory will
   also contain certificates and private keys obtained by Certbot so
   making regular backups of this folder is ideal.

### Reloading nginx ...
2020/07/05 10:27:43 [emerg] 32#32: cannot load certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/<mysite>.com/fullchain.pem": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/letsencrypt/live/<mysite>.com/fullchain.pem','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)
nginx: [emerg] cannot load certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/<mysite>.com/fullchain.pem": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/letsencrypt/live/<mysite>.com/fullchain.pem','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)
~
```